# What is the difference between "¿Qué…?" and "¿De qué…? when asking a question?

Tags: español-neutral, comparación-de-idiomas

What is the difference between "¿Qué…?" and "¿De qué…? when asking a question?
I am not asking about the differences between qué and que when making affirmations as I understand the use of 'that' and 'which'.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to respond to my question (:

Answer (score 3):

The answer to a "¿De qué...?" is a noun or noun phrase preceded by the preposition "de", and the answer to a "¿Qué...?" question is not preceded by the preposition "de".

Intuitively, "¿Qué...?" means *"What...?"* and "¿De qué...?" means *"About what...?"* or *"Of what...?"* or *"From what...?"*. However, in English the preposition in questions usually comes at the end, so "¿De qué...?" is usually *"What ... about?"* or *"What ... of?"* or *"What ... from?"*.

Examples

- ¿Qué tienes ahí? -- Mis llaves.
  *What do you have there? -- My keys.*
- ¿**De** qué estás hablando? -- (Estoy hablando) **de** tu trabajo
  *What are you talking **about**? -- (I am talking **about**) Your work.*
- ¿**De** qué tienes miedo? -- (Tendo miedo) **de** su reacción
  *What are you afraid **of**? -- (I am afraid **of**) her reaction.*

Note how the answer to "¿**De** qué...?" has "**de**" before the actual noun or noun phrase that answers the question. The intuitive check that the English translation of the question has a preposition at the end may not always work, as there may be verbs that require the preposition **de** in Spanish but require no preposition in English. An example of this is "olvidarse de algo" (*forget something*):

Comment: Good answer. Could you please provide an example of what you mention at the end, that is, a verb in English requiring no preposition but being translated into Spanish with a preposition "de" after it? I cannot come up with any example of my own and tend to think that a preposition will always be required (not necessarily "of" or "about", but perhaps "at": What are you laughing at? = ¿De qué te estás riendo?)

Comment: @Gustavson I added that caveat mostly as a defensive move, as I could not come up with examples either. But I guess you can have "¿De qué te has olvidado esta vez?" : "What have you forgotten this time?"

Comment: Excellent example!